# What is wrong with my code? I'm using MBProgressHUD

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiactivityindicatorview, unrecognized-selector

I'm using **MBProgress HUD** and I don't know what is the problem.
I have a `UIButton` that shows the **HUD**.
This is my code:

```
- (void)showHUD:(id)sender {
    HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view];
    HUD.mode = MBProgressHUDModeCustomView;
    [self.view addSubview:HUD];
    HUD.delegate = self;
    HUD.labelText = @"No Internet Connection...";
    HUD.opacity = 0.7;
    HUD.customView = 
     [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
    [HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(hudWasHidden) 
                   onTarget:self 
                 withObject:nil 
                   animated:YES];
}


- (void)hudWasHidden {

    float progress = 0.0f;
    while (progress < 1.0f) {
        progress += 0.01f;
        HUD.progress = progress;
        usleep(50000);
    }
}
```

Here is the Console log:

```
2010-06-11 17:55:26.255 Dual Search[14166:207] * -[MBProgressHUD setCustomView:]:
 unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6321220 2010-06-11 17:55:26.256 Dual 
Search[14166:207] Terminating app due to uncaught exception 
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '** -[MBProgressHUD setCustomView:]: 
unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6321220' 2010-06-11 17:55:26.256 Dual 
Search[14166:207] Stack: ( 41853515, 2505499913, 42125115, 41587990, 41584658, 
13036, 2853830, 3324117, 3332879, 3328066, 2977128, 2871789, 2903111, 49860988, 
41394236, 41390152, 49854621, 49854818, 2895329, 10508, 10362 )
```

My app always crashes when clicking the `UIButton`.

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at the console why it crashes or debug it in general.

Comment: The Console shows me this error:
-[MBProgressHUD setCustomView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6321220 2010-06-11 17:55:26.256 Dual Search[14166:207]

Comment: Ok, so `MBProgressHUD` has no method `setCustomView`. (this line ` HUD.customView = [[UIImageView alloc] ...*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common crash in Cocoa code: "unrecognized selector" is very explicit in this case. MBProgressHUD doesn't have a `customView` property, and attempting to set it is causing the crash. The `setCustomView` is the implicit selector (method) being called here, and Objective-C will crash when a called method isn't there.

Not sure what to tell you about how to accomplish what you're trying to do.